# Converting a pandas DataFrame column containing negative strings into float

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a pandas Dataframe df that contains negative strings and i would like to convert them to float:

```
NY_resitor1  NY_resitor2    SF_type        SF_resitor2 
     45          "-36"          Resis          40                  
     47           "36"          curr           34                    
      .            .           .              .                   
     49           "39"          curr           39 
     45          "-11"          curr           12 
     12          "-200"          Resis          45
```

This is the code I wrote

```
df["NY_resitor2 "]=df["NY_resitor2 "].astype(float)
```

but I have the error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: "-32"
```

what is the problem?

Comment: Works for me.  Which version of Pandas?  Also, your first value is "-36" but the error is "-32".  Any reason for the discrepancy?

Comment: actually it does that for the last number -200

Comment: Hmm, is the problem that you have embedded double quotes? i.e rather than just the string `-36` you in fact have `"-36"`? If so can you remove all these using `df['NY_resitor2'] = df['NY_resitor2'].str.replace('"', '')` and then i think you do the conversion using `as_type` or `convert_numeric` as normal

Comment: @EdChum, it works, can you please put your answer so that i might put vote it up? Thank you

Comment: I think it's unnecessary user jakevdp has added an update that covers that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this might be a case of having a strange unicode version of `"-"` somewhere in your string data. For example, this should work:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> ser = pd.Series(['-36', '36'])
>>> ser.astype(float)
0   -36
1    36
dtype: float64
```

But this doesn't, because I've replaced the standard minus sign with a [U+2212 minus sign](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2212/index.htm):

```
>>> ser2 = pd.Series(['−32', '36'])
>>> ser2.astype(float)
...
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '−32'
```

you could address this by specifically getting rid of the offending characters, using `str.replace()`:

```
>>> ser2.str.replace('−', '-').astype(float)
0   -32
1    36
dtype: float64
```

If that's not the issue, then I don't know what is!

---

Edit: another possibility is that your strings could have quotes within them. e.g.

```
>>> ser3 = pd.Series(['"-36"', '"36"'])
>>> ser3.astype(float)
...
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '"-36"'
```

In this case, you need to strip these out first:

```
>>> ser3.str.replace('"', '').astype(float)
0   -36
1    36
dtype: float64
```

Comment: what is the difference between ('−', '-'); what is the keyboard character for the other one?

Comment: I don't know of any keyboard character – I copied and pasted the character from the linked page. The reason I suspect this may be the culprit is that I've run into similar issues before when loading data from a file. You could check for it by running, e.g. ``np.unique(['-'] + [char for char in ser2.sum()])``, which in this case returns a list with two versions of the minus sign.

Comment: There is only one type when i try your suggestion. I am very confused on what seems to  be the problem here.

Comment: Strange. Could you copy-paste a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the error? That would help.

Comment: I just added an edit with another possible explanation.