# How to convert negative strings in float numbers in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series of negative strings in my dataset. I'd like to convert them into negative floats, but get the  `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-'`. I suppose there is a problem with the enconding format, so I tried to replace `-` with the Unicode `-` hyphen, but got the same error anyway.

I've tried to replace every possible Unicode code with a normal hyphen, but it didn't work.

I use Python 3.8.1 and pandas 1.0.2.

Are there any workarounds?

P.S. There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33287615/converting-a-pandas-dataframe-column-containing-negative-strings-into-float), but it didn't help.

Here what I've done:
The dataset is [here](https://reich.hms.harvard.edu/downloadable-genotypes-present-day-and-ancient-dna-data-compiled-published-papers). It's called '1240K+HO', extension .anno.

Then:

```
# open file
df = pd.read_table('v42.4.1240K_HO.anno', index_col=0, usecols=['Index', 
                                                                'Instance ID',
                                                                'Master ID', 
                                                                'Average of 95.4% date range in calBP (defined as 1950 CE)',
                                                                'Country',
                                                                'Lat.',
                                                                'Long.'],
                   na_values='..')
```

Then I try to convert strings in 'Lat.' column to float numbers.

```
# convert strings to floats
df['Lat.'] = df['Lat.'].astype(float)
```

Comment: `if not code: print("No Help")`

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please provide a [mcve] including samples of your input data, so that we cna better understand your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that there is at least one `'-'` value. That's it, just a hyphen with no figure after it.

You can do this:

```
import numpy as np

df['Lat.'] = df['Lat.'].replace('-',np.nan)
```

Then this will work:

```
df['Lat.'] = df['Lat.'].astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

in case you still get an error you can use `pd.to_numeric` with coerce to convert non-numeric elements to NaN. you can then get convert all NaN to 0 or whatever you wish from there

```
import pandas as pd

df['Lat.'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Lat.'],errors='coerce')
```